# In Codeigniter 4, the URL with 'www.' is not shown in base url()

Tags: codeigniter, nginx, codeigniter-4

In Codeigniter 4 URL with www. not shown www in base URL().

```php
$config['base_url'] = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");

$config['base_url'] .= "://". $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

$config['base_url'] .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), "", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

This source code is also not working.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

[base_url([$uri = ''[, $protocol = null]])](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#base_url)

> Returns your site base URL, as specified in your config file. Example:
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> echo base_url();
> ```

Define your base URL in your `.env` file at the root of your project. Example:

```
app.baseURL = 'http://www.your-domain.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

when you first setup a codeigniter project you will see a `env` file in your root, copy that file and rename it to `.env` env with a dot.

Then in that folder look at line `23` I think or just look for `#app.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080/'` Then Remove the hash(`#`) and just add `www.` in front of localhost like this `app.baseURL = 'http://www.yourdomain.com/'`

Also Remember to change your `$baseURL` in `app\Config\App.php` to your domain.

***FYI:***

**What is a .env file?**
A .env file or dotenv file is a simple text configuration file for controlling your Applications environment constants.

[I recommend you look at the codeignter official docs aswell](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/intro/index.html)

Comment: You don't have to make any change in `app\Config\App.php` since declaring `app.baseURL = 'http://www.yourdomain.com/'` in the .env file provides the same results.

Comment: I personally do but its up to the person